# Array and For loop help - return largest number in array consisting of subarrays

Tags: arrays, sub-array

The below code should return an array consisting of the largest number from each provided sub-array.

```
function largestOfFour(arr) {
  var i = 0;
  var j= 0;
  var collection = [];
  var max = 0;

  for(i; i < arr.length; i++){
    for(j; j < arr[i].length; j++){
      if(arr[i][j]> max){
        max =arr[i][j];
      } 
    }
    collection.push(max);
    max = 0;
  }

  return collection;
}

largestOfFour([[13, 27, 18, 26], [4, 5, 1, 3], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000,1001  ,857, 1]]);
```

The output on the above code outputs [27,0,0,0] when I run it as is. It gives the correct answer when I declare and initialize i and j within each respective for loops: 
[27,5,39,1001]. My question is what is the difference? I thought it would be equivalent to declare i and j and initialize them to 0 whether inside or outside the for loops.

Answer (score 2):

You're never resetting `j` to 0, so it's ignoring the contents of each sub-array after the first. When you initialize `j` in its loop declaration, it's properly reset, so the code works.

Comment: var j=0; inside the first for would fix it too.